# Omniture Data Warehouse Segments Issue

Tags: bigdata, data-warehouse, adobe-analytics

Currently, I'm trying to create a segment filter called "Only Search Page" which filters out one particular server from a list of several thousand. Currently, I'm a little stuck and it might be easier to explain with screenshots.

In the Segment Manager I set up a segment to check for equality(inside RED box), when I do this, I can see the filter working(inside the ORANGE box).
[image: Image One]

However, when I go to review the report OR when I go to export the Data with Data Warehouse the filter doesn't apply. As you can see in the second image, with the GREEN box, the segment should be active.
[image]

When I select this segment from the list of available segments in Data Warehouse, my reports still contain all the other servers.

I would really appreciate anyone's help/guidance on this situation! Still new to this Analytics System.

Comment: This is a matter of scope. Basically your segment vs. report is saying "show me all server values where server equals foo at least once for the visitor.  So, if a visitor pops foo on one page and bar on another page, it's going to show both.  If you want to use a segment to only show only foo, change the scope to hit.

Comment: Thank you again. That worked perfectly, if you'd like to copy and paste this in the answer section I'll be sure to mark it as answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a matter of scope. Basically your segment vs. report is saying "show me all server values where server equals foo at least once for the visitor. So, if a visitor pops foo on one page and bar on another page, it's going to show both. If you want to use a segment to only show only foo, change the scope to hit.